# Character recognition using Tesseract-OCR and OpenCV (Cannot capture '[' and ']')

Tags: opencv, python-imaging-library, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am trying to extract text part of an image using Tesseract-OCR and OpenCV in Python. I have attached an example image as below:

[image]

It cannot capture '[' and ']' properly. The extraction output of this image is (*testScreenshot*):

```
Elektronik Mühendisliği Bölümü 
Ozturkfat)osmaniye.edu.tr 
0328 8271000
```

Expected result is **`[at]`** instead of **`fat)`**. If I change the language to English rather than Turkish, **`fat]`** is captured. Don't you that this is weird ? How can I capture properly this as **`[at]`** with the setting of Turkish?
Thanks in advance

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
plainText = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(testScreenshot), lang='tur', config=tessdata_dir_config)
print(plainText)
```

Edit: If I give only '[' and ']', it also do not capture inside of the bracket as well. Example input image is:

[image]

The output:

```
rolfat)
rolfat)
```

As you can see that, right half of the image ([at]) not captured because I remove the beginning text (rol). Somehow, it is sensitive to the characters of [ and ]. They might be sharper on the image compared to other characters. This can be a reason ?

Comment: Threshold your image first and see if your can distinguish those characters. Your image may have too small characters and too noisy background.

Comment: I can try thresholding exactly. However, I don't think so that input images are neither small or noisy because entire images are captured through web scraping. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Are the characters correctly classified individually?

Comment: What you mean for that?

Comment: If you pass an image containing just the miss-classified characters, like just  '[' or  ']', what kind of result you get? Are you getting a proper recognition?

Comment: @eldesgraciado there is no recognition at all. I edit the question based on your question. Any suggestions?